# Circular Doubly Linked List toString not working

Tags: java, tostring, doubly-linked-list

I have a toString with a helper method to print out the results of a circular linked list class I created. This is it:

```
/**
   * Returns a String version of this.
   *
   * @return  A String description of this.
   */
  public String toString(){
    String string = "";
    DoubleNode<E> current = this.head;
    string += stringHelper(this.head);
    return string;
  }
  //Helps the full to string method
  private String stringHelper(DoubleNode<E> node){
    String string = "";
    if(node == null){
      return string;
    }
    System.out.println("Node value: " + node.getValue());
    node = node.getNextLink();
    if(node == this.head){
      string += node.getValue();
      return string;
    }
    else{
      string += node.getValue();
      return (stringHelper(node.getNextLink()) + ", " + string);
    }
  }
```

However, it appears to not be working. I have a test case where it should print out 40, 10, 2, but it prints out only 40, 10. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What did you find when you traced out its execution with pen and paper? Or when you stepped through it with a debugger?

Comment: The print statement prints out 40 and then 2 for some reason, but I don't know why it did. I don't have any experience with debuggers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Sorry for posting this, as I should have done this on my own. I ended up doing:

```
/**
   * Returns a String version of this.
   *
   * @return  A String description of this.
   */
  public String toString(){
    String string = "";
    DoubleNode<E> current = this.head;
    string += stringHelper(this.head);
    return string;
  }
  //Helps the full to string method
  private String stringHelper(DoubleNode<E> node){
    String string = "";
    if(node == null){
      return string;
    }
    string+= node.getValue();
    string+= ", ";
    node = node.getNextLink();
    if(node == this.head){
      return string;
    }
    else{
      string += node.getValue();
      return (string + ", " + stringHelper(node.getNextLink()));
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should replace the recursive call `stringHelper(node.getNextLink())` with `stringHelper(node)`, as you call `node.getNextLink()` twice in `stringHelper()` method which is not right.

Comment: When I replace it like you said, it simply only prints out the first element, as there is no longer any traversal.

Comment: It's hard to give the right answer without the whole class code. But anyway your problem is that you call `node.getNextLink()` twice